# Как получить встроенные изображения из сообщения и корректно их отобразить? (C#, MailKit, MimeKit)

Tags: c#, email, webbrowser, mime, mailkit

Как получить встроенные изображения из сообщения и корректно их отобразить? (C#, MailKit, MimeKit)
Компонент в который выводится сообщение - WebBrowser

[image: Пример]

Код получившийся у меня для чтения писем (встроенные изображения не показывает)

```
_listMessageSummary = await _openFolder.FetchAsync(_uidsListMessages, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure | MessageSummaryItems.Full, _token);
foreach (var summary in _listMessageSummary)
            {
                if (summary.UniqueId == messageUid)
                {
                    labelDate.Text = string.Join("", "Дата: ", summary.Date.DateTime);
                    labelTheme.Text = string.Join("", "Тема: ", summary.Envelope.Subject);
                    labelFrom.Text = string.Join("", "От: ", summary.Envelope.From);
                    labelTo.Text = string.Join("", "Кому: ", summary.Envelope.To);
                    if (summary.HtmlBody != null && summary.HtmlBody.IsHtml)
                    {
                        var body = (TextPart)await _openFolder.GetBodyPartAsync(messageUid, summary.HtmlBody, _token);
                        webBrowser.DocumentText = body.Text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var body = (TextPart)await _openFolder.GetBodyPartAsync(messageUid, summary.TextBody, _token);
                        webBrowser.DocumentText = body.Text.Replace("\r\n", "<br>");
                    }
                    if (summary.Attachments.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        labelAttachments.Visible = true;
                        labelAttachments.Height = 30;
                        _attachments = summary;
                    }
                    if (((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow != null && ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.Cells[_cellStatus].Value.ToString().Equals("Новое"))
                    {
                        ((DataGridView)sender).CurrentRow.Cells[_cellStatus].Value = "Прочитано";
                        _openFolder.SetFlags(messageUid, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
                        dgvMessages.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[_cellStatus].Style.Font = new Font(dgvMessages.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                        dgvMessages.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[_cellStatus].Style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат

```
if (summary.Body is BodyPartMultipart)
{
   var listBodPartBasic = summary.BodyParts.SkipWhile(x =>
   {
       return !x.ContentType.MediaType.Equals("image");
   }).ToList();
   if (listBodPartBasic != null)
   {
      var listMimePart = listBodPartBasic.Select(bpd =>
      {
          return (MimePart)_openFolder.GetBodyPart(summary.UniqueId, bpd);
      }).ToList();
       // код для сохранения изображений на диск                          
   }
}
```